# Trying to show more products with block type="catalog/product_list

Tags: product-list, blocks

I'm using

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" productCount="16" category_id="14" template="catalog/product/home_list.phtml" }}

for show products from in my home from one category but it only show me 9 products in 4 colums and 3 rows.

I tryied to put

> _productsCount=”10“

but no works, some sugestion please?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it's actually possible, but try to set the parameter "limit". If that doesn't work you might have to reqire the product_list to accept a limit as a parameter, usually the limit is set by calling the setLimit method.